# how to manage multiple branches on stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

How I can create following branches on stash and push code into them using git.

1. Development1
2. Development2
3. Production

Please let me know your thoughts for the same.

Answer (score 0):

To create your branches:

```
git checkout -b Development1
git checkout -b Development2
git checkout -b Production
```

To push your branches:

```
git push origin Development1
git push origin Development2
git push origin Production
```

#### Edit:

`origin` is your default repository.

Use `git remote -v` to see your repositories and `git remote add [name] [url]` to add a new repository.

Sample: (push your branch to remote repository)

```
git remote add somerepo https://somerepo.com/somerepo
git push somerepo Production
```

Comment: we don,t need to specify repository name along with branch while push the data?

Comment: How haroldo, please can you explain me little bit more about stash.

Comment: I have one query, if we had there branches than code will be different for all three branches?, I am asking these becoz I am fresher in stash, no understanding about this.

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried to push code in development1 branch-----------------$ git push origin Development1
error: src refspec Development1 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://admin@localhost:7990/scm/trd/repos2.git'

Comment: development1 should be Development1?